# RatingBar set float value dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin

Trying to set float value dynamically for RatingBar android but not working code I am trying to set is rating.rating = 3.2.toFloat() and XML is.

```
   `<RatingBar 
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_by_four"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:max="5"
        android:rating="3.6"
        android:stepSize="0.1" />`
```

expecting some customization things for RatingBar thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

 `rating.rating = 3.2F`

instead of:

`rating.rating = 3.2.toFloat()`

And add after this:

`rating.invalidate()`

Comment: the value coming from the backend so cant change have to use in that way only

Comment: Try add after changing rating `rating.invalidate()`